# Pass onclick function on template string javascript

Tags: javascript, html, string, templates

I am using es6 template strings concept to pass tags dynamically. I have an onClick function for a tag which is not called when passed to template strings.

Here is my code :

```
const markup = 
 <div class="person">
    <h2>
        ${person.name}
    </h2>
    <p class="location">${person.location}</p>
    <p class="bio" onclick="person(${person.bio},${person.location})">${person.bio}</p>
 </div>
;
```

I need to pass that function and that function should be called.

Please help me fix it.

Comment: Have you checked the html output, which the browser receives?

Comment: Yes nothing happening when clicked

Comment: Then add also the html output (html and javascript) so we can try to reproduce it.